# Is this an inner automorphism of $\mathcal{Q}_{8}$?

Tags: group-theory

Here, we have $$\mathcal{Q}_8=\{1,-1, i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}$$

---

**Question.** Consider the automorphism $\psi: \mathcal{Q}_8\rightarrow\mathcal{Q}_8$ given by $$\psi(1)=1,\quad\psi(-1)=-1,\quad\psi(i)=-k,\quad\psi(-i)=k,$$ $$\psi(j)=-i,\quad\psi(-j)=i,\quad\psi(k)=j,\quad\psi(-k)=-j.$$ Is $\psi$ an inner automorphism? *The order of this automorphism is 3.*

---

**My attempt at a solution.** Suppose $\psi$ is an inner automorphism. Then, the automorphism is given by the conjugation action; that is $\rho_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$ for all $g,h\in \mathcal{Q}_8.$

So, let $g=h=i$; then $$ghg^{-1}=i\cdot i\cdot -i=-1\cdot -i=i\neq -k.$$ Now, let $g=j$ and $h=i$; then $$ghg^{-1}=jij^{-1}=-k\cdot-j=-i\neq-k.$$ Now, let $g=k$ and $h=i$; then $$ghg^{-1}=kik^{-1}=j\cdot -k=-i\neq -k.$$ The $g=-i, -j, -k$ will all give similar results.

Since the conjugation action isn't satisfied; $\psi$ is not an inner automorphism.

---

Is this the right track? If so, is there a more elegant way of determing whether an automorphism is inner or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, I don't think there's anything much faster than trying to find out. In this specific case, since it's always the case for any two elements of the group that $gh=hg$ or $gh=-hg$, then you know that conjugating any element $h$ of the group by another element $g$ will give either $h$ or $-h$; so as soon as you confirm that $\psi$ is an automorphism and that $\psi$ takes $i$ somewhere other than $i$ or $-i$, you know it can't be inner.

Comment: Ah, I see, I see. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Remark that $Int(Q_8)=Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ is of order $4$, if you know that $\psi$ is of order $3$ then clearly (well by Lagrange's theorem to be very accurate) $\psi$ cannot belong to $Int(Q_8)$. I think that's why the order of the automorphism is emphasized.

Comment: Oh yeah! Totally forgot what the centre of $Q_8$ is so couldn't utilise your remark properly. So thanks a lot. Feel free to submit your comment as an answer so I can mark it as such.